# How a dataframe with a dynamic number of columns can be filtered?

Tags: python, pandas, filter, dynamic, nan

I download data using url calls. The dataframe' columns are not static. For example, with one url call the dataframe can contain `x` columns while with another url call it can contain `y` columns etc.

The column which is always included in the dataframe is the `id` column. The potential columns' names are: `col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6` (except of the `id` column).

I would like to select only the rows of the dataframe that they are not include `nan` in all columns. There is a circumstance that the dataframe can contain only the `id` column and therefore there is no need to select any rows.

Lets say that one single url call gives the following dataframe using this hypothetical code:

```
data = {'id': [1000,2000,3000,4000],
        'col1': [np.nan,25000,np.nan,np.nan],
        'col2': [np.nan,27000,np.nan,30000],
        'col3': [28000,np.nan,np.nan,25000]
        }

dfexp = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['id', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3'])

     id     col1     col2     col3
0  1000      NaN      NaN  28000.0
1  2000  25000.0  27000.0      NaN
2  3000      NaN      NaN      NaN
3  4000      NaN  30000.0  25000.0
```

For example from the above dataframe I would like to select only the rows `0`, `1` and `3`.

A second url call can give the potential dataframe using the following hypothetical code:

```
data2 = {'id': [1500,2500,3500,4500],
        'col1': [1900,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
        'col4': [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
        'col5': [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
        'col6': [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,25000]
        }

dfexp2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['id', 'col1', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6'])

     id     col1 col4 col5 col6
0  1500      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  2500  25000.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  3500      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  4500      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

From this second dataframe I want only to select row `1`.

In general, I would like to select only the rows that have at least 1 `non-nan` element. I am a beginner and the dynamic thing is tricky for me. Do you have any thoughts?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try:  `df = df.set_index('id').dropna().reset_index()`

Comment: one slight modification: `df = df.set_index('id').dropna(how="all").reset_index()`

Comment: He wants to get rows that have at least one `NaN` value, this code doesn't give a row with all `NaN` value.

Comment: Oh, omitted a parameter.  Thanks for reminder.

Comment: Shouldn't it that **"Select rows with at least 1 non-nan element"** equivalent to **"Exclude rows with all nan elements"** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df.set_index('id').dropna(how='all').reset_index()
```

**Explanation**

As you are a beginner, let me explain it a bit.

This will (Step 1) temporarily set column `id` as index and then (Step 2) drop all rows with ALL `nan` elements (except the original column `id` as it is now index and index will not be checked for the `nan` values in the `dropna()` call.)   We need to include parameter `how='all'`  (thanks for reminder of anon01) because the default is `how='any'` which will drop the rows whenever any one column contains `nan`.  After that, we can (Step 3) restore the column `id` by moving back from index to column by the `reset_index()` call.

Comment: Thanks a lot @SeaBean :)